# Expo app with SDK 48 Cocoapods issues when EAS BUILD

Tags: react-native, expo

My app runs on SDK 48 and I tried to run a build using EAS BUILD and Im getting this errors:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In Podfile:
    EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 9.5.0)
    RNFBAnalytics (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics`) was resolved to 10.8.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Analytics (~> 7.6.0) was resolved to 7.6.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Core (= 7.6.0)
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMaps":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-google-maps (from `/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (= 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
        GoogleMaps
    react-native-google-maps (from `/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      GoogleMaps (= 7.0.0)
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watchAll",
    "types:check": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/open-sans": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "10.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "10.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "10.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "10.8.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.0.1",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.9.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.6.0",
    "expo-camera": "^13.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-facebook": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jest-circus": "^29.1.2",
    "jotai": "^1.6.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.32.1",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^2.1.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "@types/react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/react-native-global-props": "^1.1.1",
    "detox": "^19.12.5",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.4.1",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=7.0.0",
    "node": "16.15.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{jsx,tsx,ts,js,css,md}": "prettier --write",
    "*.{js,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  },
  "detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim": {
        "binaryPath": "bin/Exponent.app",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 11"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any clue how to solve this that is breaking my head please!

Comment: Hi did you manage to solve this? I have a very similar issue, i am trying to implement facebook-authentication in my app and when i run `expo run:ios` i keep getting `CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and fixed by removing expo-firebase-core, which was conflicting with @react-native-firebase.

For more information please see:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17543

Comment: Let me see if I remember because I didn't document how I fixed it :(